Associated with outsiders
What's specifically depicted here?



I think

 You are referring to Area 51 in the NEVADA DESERT!


 Like Stiv said the flag points to 36th state which joined the USA which is NEVADA, the title points to aliens and green strip points to a rectangle with 3x17 or area of 51!


I think you now have it but it's not because of the colour - it's a rot13(guerr ol friragrra erpgnatyr fb vg unf nern svsgl bar)

This is the intended answer! And yes @Stiv is correct

@stiv thanks I thought about area of the rectangle but could not see this far

I think you are:

 Green with envy, an expression used to describe someone who is particularly jealous of others who have something they themselves want (as, for example, an outsider might feel, hence the title).

The rebus is explained as follows:

 The US flag is divided into 50 boxes (reflecting its 50 states), and the 36th (counting from top left along the rows) is highlighted. The 36th state to join the union was Nevada, whose common 2-letter abbreviation is NV.

 What we therefore have here is the colour green with NV (which sounds like 'envy' when spelled out), i.e. GREEN WITH ENVY!


Good attempt, but this is not it. You have the correct rot13(fgngr) though! Try to make sense of the right part of the puzzle.

@Prim3numbah Really?? Well, that's interesting. I've rarely been more certain of an answer fitting so well... I shall think again.

Your answer fitted very well, but the answer I had in mind also took the size in consideration which you figured out in the comments under the answer of @PDT :)
